# How to Set onClicklistener Method of ImageView in Android widget?

Tags: android, click, widget, imageview

I am developing and android analog clock widget with and Imageview on it I need to start and activity when the image view is clicked, any ideas (I am basically a Java developer but new to Android)

- It does not show me any logs in logcat I have tried

  ```
   String action = intent.getAction();
   Log.v("info",action);
   Log.i("info",action);
   Log.d("info",action);
  ```

  any suggestions ...

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageButton instead of ImageView in your application.